# Bash, no-arguments warning, and case decisions

Tags: bash

I am learning bash.

I would like to do a simple script that, when not arguments given, shows some message. And when I give numers as argument,s depending on the value, it does one thing or another.

I would also like to know suggestions for the best online manuals for beginners in bash

Thanks

Answer (score 229, accepted):

```
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'some message'
    exit 0
fi

case "$1" in
    1) echo 'you gave 1' ;;
    *) echo 'you gave something else' ;;
esac
```

The [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) is pretty good. In spite of its name, it does treat the basics.

Comment: RE: "exit 0".  I don't know if exiting the script was what he had in mind.  But yes, that's an excellent guide.

Comment: I interpreted "and" as "otherwise", assuming that the message would be some help text. But I'm sure Werner is able to figure out what that line does and whether he wants it :)

Comment: thanks, of course!

and last thing, how can i turn off error messages ib the script, so they are not shown to the shell?

Comment: You mean the errors coming out of a particular program you're calling? You can put `> /dev/null` and/or `2> /dev/null` after that to send its standard output and/or standard error streams into oblivion.

Comment: You can also do `exec 2>/dev/null` to nuke standard error globally, for all commands in the script. Not that I think that's a good idea, though.

Comment: If you consider a missing argument something bad (like the script then cannot perform successfully), return something different than 0 (`exit 1`). There are further conventions about return/exit codes, that you can find online quickly, but the important point is that it should not be 0, which indicates success.

Comment: @CameronHudson Are you sure you're using bash, not sh?

Comment: Looks like some good extra info. here: https://www.shellhacks.com/print-usage-exit-if-arguments-not-provided/

Comment: The link provided in the answer is no longer available, please consider updating the link with another value.

Comment: @RakibFiha It works for me. The guide is also hosted in several other places, so you can just search for the name.

Answer (score 34):

If only interested in bailing if a particular argument is missing, [Parameter Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html#USAGEMESSAGE) is great:

```
#!/bin/bash
# usage-message.sh

: ${1?"Usage: $0 ARGUMENT"}
#  Script exits here if command-line parameter absent,
#+ with following error message.
#    usage-message.sh: 1: Usage: usage-message.sh ARGUMENT
```

Answer (score 18):

### Example

```
 if [ -z "$*" ]; then echo "No args"; fi
```

### Result

```
No args
```

### Details

**-z** is the unary operator for length of string is zero.
`$*` is all arguments.
The quotes are for safety and encapsulating multiple arguments if present.

Use `man bash` and search (**/** key) for "unary" for more operators like this.

Comment: A (minor) problem with this is that it doesn't distinguish between passing no arguments and passing an empty string as argument. That may be important in some contexts. Using [ $# -eq 0 ] one can handle both cases properly.

Comment: Ah, the subtleties of (ba)sh programming... This is why I hate it.

Comment: think of `-z` as _mizzing_

Comment: I used `-z "$1"` which was enough

Answer (score 1):

Old but I have reason to rework the answer now thanks to some previous confusion:

```
if [[ $1 == "" ]] #Where "$1" is the positional argument you want to validate 

 then
 echo "something"
 exit 0

fi
```

This will echo "Something" if there is no positional argument $1. It does not validate that $1 contains specific information however.

Comment: `$#` is explicitly the integer count of the number of arguments; it will either be "0", and you will echo "something" even though there are no arguments, or it will be some positive number, and you will echo "something" correctly. But the check itself will never do anything, regardless of the input or lack of input you use -- it will *always* report that `$#` contains a value. So this is completely wrong and will never work as claimed.

Comment: Are you completely positive of that? I have several scripts that work as intended using this exact format. Upon reading your response I even retested both for the match and lack thereof.  $# will not contain a value if not specified, if there is no positional argument to match what ever # is in your scenario. It makes no sense why bash would assume a value in a positional argument that isn't there.

Comment: Try `echo $#` as the contents of a script /tmp/test.sh, then run it under /bin/bash as well as /bin/sh (or /bin/dash and whatever other shell implementations you have available. `/tmp/test.sh` will echo "0" to the console, as will `/bin/dash /tmp/test.sh`. On the other hand, `/tmp/test.sh foo` will echo "1", and `/tmp/test.sh first second` will echo "2".

Comment: As per `man bash`, in the section "Special Parameters", "The shell treats several parameters specially.  These parameters may only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.", and "#      Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal." It is likewise mandated by POSIX as described in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05_02

Comment: Sorry looks like there was a miscommunication! I meant # as a place holder for the specific positional argument (i.e, $2 if you meant the second argument) not literal $#. 

After reviewing your above you are absolutely correct, a literal $# will always resolve to the number of arguments. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: That makes more sense, but it is also different from what the top answer is offering. Your suggestion would claim that there are no arguments, if the first argument is the null string, e.g. `/tmp/test.sh ''` will report that `$#` is "1", because the positional argument exists, but your test will compare it to an empty string and conclude that there is nothing there. That may or may not matter depending on the use case, but it is something worth pointing out. If you use $# -ge then you could test whether the number of parameters is at least X.

Answer (score 0):

If there is not only 1 argument, then print usage and exit

```bash
if [[ $# != 1 ]] ; then
  echo 'USAGE: bin/siege COOKIE'
  exit 0
fi
```